# Django(1.11) rest framework post user.id in nested serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to get user.id in the background when user creates a delivery address and product data in models and i get this error
`ull value in column "ordered_by_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (66, 5051, tetsst, 2018-10-11, f, null).`
Which means that user.id is not being added to models for some reason.

My models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.FloatField()
    name = models.CharField(default='gift', max_length=512)
    ordered_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    purchased = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Delivery(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField()  #gotta change that one to charfield
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
                                 message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'."
                                         " Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=16, blank=False)
    delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

my serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            "name",
            "price",
        )

class ProductDeliverySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Delivery
        fields = (
            "address",
            "city",
            "country",
            "zip_code",
            "phone_number",
            "product",
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        product_data = validated_data.pop('product')
        print(validated_data, product_data)
        product = Product.objects.create(**product_data)
        delivery = Delivery.objects.create(product=product, **validated_data)
        return delivery
```

When i do print/test validated data it actually shows that 'form'/POST is complete 
`{'address': 'address here', 'city': 'City is here', 'country': 'Country is here', 'zip_code': 3333, 'phone_number': '+19991234567', 'ordered_by': <SimpleLazyObject: <User: testuser>>}`
output for product_data  `OrderedDict([('name', 'tetsst'), ('price', 5051.0)])`

my views.py

```
class ProductList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(ordered_by=self.request.user)


class DeliveryList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Delivery.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductDeliverySerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(ordered_by=self.request.user)
```

Comment: In your sterilizer  there is no ordered_by field specified.

Comment: I want to keep it in the background tho, so it does that in background ( like request.user) and just do it in the background. without actual need to post it, not sure if i can do it now tho. im quite new to DRF

Comment: What is the output of print(productdata)?

Comment: @a_k_v updated the post output is ```OrderedDict([('name', 'test_product'), ('price', 5051.0)])
```

Comment: Thats the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `product = Product.objects.create(**product_data)`. The product_data not containing any user object. It is missing. This may the problem of how you constructed input JSON. add the `ordered_by` in validated data to product_data.
Something like this:

```
product_data['ordered_by'] = validated_data.pop('ordered_by')
```

Comment: oh my lord, that does indeed work ( tho i slightly edited my Product serializer)
```class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            "name",
            "price",
            "ordered_by",
        )
        read_only_fields = ('ordered_by',)
```